# Construct an int from binary "components" in C

Tags: c, arrays, binary, arduino

I have several equations that will return the binary value for each of the three bits in my number.

I am programing this in C which is a new language for me.

So let's say my equations return `Y0 = 1` , `Y1 = 0` and `Y2 = 1` (`101`); I want to store that value as `5`.

Is this possible in C if these values are returned by different equations?

I know how to do it by multiplying, but I am looking for a function or something which I imagine is already built into C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such luck. You have to multiply (or shift, which is the same)

```
unsigned Y0 = 1, Y1 = 0, Y2 = 1, val;

val = (Y0 * 4)  + (Y1 * 2)  + (Y2 * 1);  /* parens */
val = (Y0 << 2) + (Y1 << 1) + (Y2 << 0); /* redundant */
```

Answer (score 4):

Just bitshift:

```
Y0 | (Y1 << 1) | (Y2 << 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such function in the C standard library.

You will need to do:

```
int x = (Y2 << 2) | (Y1 << 1) | (Y0 << 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not very popular, you do have an alternative, in that you can use bit fields to perform the type of operation you're talking about. So, on [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/bOsoU), the following code would perform the action you've suggested.

```
union combine {
    struct bits{
        int x: 1;
        int y: 1;
        int z: 1;
        int pad : 29;
    } bitvalues;
    int value;
};

int main() {
    union combine test;
    test.bitvalues.x = 1;
    test.bitvalues.y = 0;
    test.bitvalues.z = 1;
    test.bitvalues.pad = 0;
    printf("result: %d\n", test.value);
    return 0;
}
```

It's important to note however, that because you're using a combination of a bitfields and a union, **this is not a portable solution**.  It is dependent on the order that you define your bits in, matching the bit/byte order for integer on that machine.  So, there is a way to do it without bit shifting, but you're almost certainly better off going with the bit shifting solution.